# first time using SSRS web server, setting up website

Tags: sharepoint, reporting-services, webserver, rdl

its my first time using this and as a newbie I have many questions. Any help are appreciated.

My ultimate goal is to have reports created from database that will be able to be accessed by other end users on website so they can view/filter the report data online in a shared way with some user control settings.

So I have already made my reports in the visual studio linking to databases.
And I have also set up the Reporting Service Configuration Manager so that I can access SSRS home page and the site setting at http://'127.0.0.1'/Reports/Pages/Folder.aspx

Now my question is, how will the other end users be able to get onto the website and get access to the reports I created with SSRS? Do I upload the reports in .rdl on my report site manually or do I deploy it from VS? How do I turn my '127.0.0.1/Reports' into a public site for other user's access? Or do I have to create it using a sharepoint?

Thanks so much, I need a guidance to head toward the right direction! :)

Answer (score 0):

> Now my question is, how will the other end users be able to get onto the website and get access to the reports I created with SSRS?

Users will need 2 things from you to access the site:  the server name/address, and a means of authenticating to it.  By default, authentication is handle via Windows domain auth (which you *can* change, with varying degrees of effort...).

> Do I upload the reports in .rdl on my report site manually or do I deploy it from VS?

It actually makes no difference in the end; do whichever you find easier.  (There are also plenty of other ways to deploy reports, such as through powershell!)

> How do I turn my '127.0.0.1/Reports' into a public site for other user's access?

Well you're halfway there - At this point, you could probably open up your firewall (port 80, maybe 443 depending on your config), and have people connect to your computer via IP or hostname - for example, if your computer's IP was 12.34.56.78, they could visit 12.34.56.78/Reports/ and access the site.  If you have a means of creating a URL and pointing it to your SSRS server, you might need to open the configuration manager again and bind that URL to SSRS.